# из java project в maven в intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, package, рефакторинг

Изменю вопрос: есть два проекта с разной структурой. Нужно перенести несколько взаимосвязанных классов из из одного проекта в другой. При переносе в intellij idea с помощью Refactor -> Copy внутри классов путь и импорты не меняются автоматически. Есть ли способ в intellij idea перенести класс в другой проект, чтобы package внутри класса изменился автоматически? 
Например:
был package com.project.system.business; стал: package project1.system1.business; следовательно чтобы и импорты изменились автоматически

Comment: покажите структуру вашего проекта

Comment: Был: com\project\car\ (и здесь несколько папок с классами), а в мавене ...\src\main\java\car\(и здесь несколько папок с классами), т.е. названия packege внутри классов должно поменяться

Comment: Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.